# Can't set a subview below another subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is the scenario:

[image]

I have this `UIViewController`of a **MainVC** class.

Inside this **MainVC** i have a `UITextField` of a **TextFieldVC** class.

Now inside **TextFieldVC.m** i'm creating a `UITableView` that should be inserted *below* the `UITextField`with this code

```
            //TextFieldVC.m

            UIView *rootView = [self.window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

            [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
            [rootView insertSubview:self.autoCompleteTableView
                             belowSubview:self];
```

where `autoCompleteTableView` is the `UITableView`. The `UITableView` will be created whenever the user starts editing the `UITextField`, that is an `@Outlet` in **MainVC.m**

Now the problem is that this `autoCompleteTableView`is created above the `UITextField` and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible explanation for what is happening is that `rootView` does not have the text field among its subviews. Try this out:

```
        [self.superview insertSubview:self.autoCompleteTableView
                         belowSubview:self];
```

By doing this you are ensuring that you add the table view to the same view that also contains the text field, so the ordering between the two subviews can be enforced.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour, based on sergio answer.

If I have the root view frame at another location than 0,0 (exemple: `self.view.frame= CGRectMake(0, 1100, 300, 400);`).

= when I call this line on the control, the root view return at 0,0 !!!

```
  [self.superview insertSubview:self.autoCompleteTableView
                         belowSubview:self];
```

Any idea?